# Convert ETRS89 points to CARTO Lat Long

Tags: postgis, postgresql, carto, geocoding, srid

I'm new in Geographic Information Systems and programming.

I have some points referencing Barcelona, Spain. These points are comming from City Hall's opendata site. They say they are in ETRS89 reference system. I don't really know what it means. I need them in Latitude Longitude system so I can pass them to CARTO, OpenStreetMaps, GoogleMaps...

Here some points example:

`430344431;4582166733
430344431;4582261851
430344431;4582060238
430344431;4582301912
430344431;4582201841
430344431;4581863161
430344431;4580885282
430344431;4582098182
430344431;4582313751
430344431;4581900735
430344431;4581281417`

Comment: Ask them in which EPSG code the data are or at least give us a link to that opendata site.

Comment: Here is the dataset http://opendata.bcn.cat/opendata/ca/catalog/URBANISME_I_INFRAESTRUCTURES/fonts/ 
I don't know the UTM i've just asked them. Some where i've found that barcelona is in the UTM 31N. But i'm not shure

Comment: Hi @user30184 here looks like Barcelona is in UTM 31 http://www.dices.net/poblaciones/4292.html

Comment: Then I suppose that you want to reproject data from this http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/ed50-utm-zone-31n/ into this http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4326/.

Comment: I guess this is what i need @user30184

Comment: I think there is something wrong with that `fonts` dataset. For instance, one of the pairs of coordinates is the same. I will answer you with another dataset from the same open data portal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After importing the dataset into CARTO, you have to update your `the_geom` column using the following SQL query:

```
UPDATE 
  horts_urbans
SET
  the_geom = ST_Transform(ST_SetSrid(ST_MakePoint(etrs89_coord_x, etrs89_coord_y), 25831), 4326)
```

I have used the `horts_urbans` dataset from City of Barcelona open data portal.

Comment: your solution on the fonts dataset gives this error:
'geometry srid (25831) does not match column (4326) '

Comment: Are you talking that all x values are the same so that's why dataset is wrong? @ramiroaznar

Comment: Another problem can be that values are in mm not in meters. I'm thinking in preprocess the data with Proj4 or you think i can get this via sql?

Comment: Fixed. It should run OK with `horts_urbans` dataset. But as I said, I believe `fonts` x coordinates are wrong.

Comment: Effectively the dataset is wrong, i've done a script in Python and here are the results https://perecullera.carto.com/viz/48d9e518-5fde-11e6-a807-0e3ff518bd15/public_map

Comment: But your query still giving a `GetProj4StringSPI : Cannot find SRID(4386) in spatial_ref_sys`
Here is what i used with python's Proj4 

`Proj("+proj=utm +zone=31 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs") //in
Proj(proj='latlong',datum='WGS84') //out`

Comment: It worked for the first row of the dataset as this is the unique correct data

Comment: Sorry. The first error was because I mixed the `srid`s, now I misspelled the Mercator one: `4326` is the good one. Anyway, I highly recommend you to have a look at the PostGIS functions I have used in order to understand what you are doing. In doing so, next time you have an error like those ones, you will be able to understand what is going on.

Comment: Thanks for your help!!! Now it works althought the bad dataset,. 
Whre can i get more info about PostGIS?

Comment: Glad to help. More info about PostGIS: http://postgis.net/documentation/